# With asp.net forms client validation, how to check if the page is valid or not without triggering the actual validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

With asp.net forms client validation, we can call Page_ClientValidate() to validate the page, and then check Page_IsValid to determine if the page is valid or not. However, because the page is validated, so the error messages are shown on the page. Is there a way to check if the page is valid or not without calling Page_ClientValidate() in javascript?

Comment: "However, because the page is validated, so the error messages are shown on the page. " Is this what you menat to type? Can You clarify what it is you are asking do you want to validate on the client or not?

Comment: on the client using javascript, because I called Page_ClientValidate(), so the form is validated and the flag Page_IsValid is set, but it also causes the error message to display in the <asp:ValidationSummary ... /> control. What I'm looking for is to be able to check if the page is valid without showing those error messages. Thanks

Comment: ?? I guess I still don't really understand. Do you want to validate your input Yes/No?  Presumambly Yes!  Do you want to validate on the client Yes/No? (Presumably Yes!)  Do you want to alert user regarding input Yes/No (Presumably Yes!)  . If yes the you can use the ASP Validation controls (with validation summary)  they will handle validation on the client without you having to write any JavaScript at all! Or you can NOT use ASP validation control and write your own JavaScript validation code (using Page_ClientValidate() ).

Comment: "Do you want to validate your input Yes/No?" actually no. I want to check if the page is valid without any side effect. Calling Page_ClientValidate() causes a side effect which is the error msg being displayed on the page. And also, using Page_ClientValidate() is not "write your own JavaScript validation code", it's just triggering the validation you created with asp.net forms validation.